# add this api in flex3

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex3

in one flex application, i have to implement the addthis api, means i have to give options of sharing the application on social media  like facebook, twitter etc, there is one api provided by

[addthis.com](http://addthis.com)

bt i am not getting how to work in to this, i m still using flex3, as ma project is in flex3,

can n e body have n e idea of how to use these sharing api, in to flex, thanx in advance

Comment: How about you link to, or give us information about their API?  We don't want to dissect their site looking for it.

Comment: hi Flextras, i didn't get u properly, well the functionanity they(addthis.com) give is awesome, they give u baked code, and u just need to put that in ur page, i m flex developer, my php devloper has already done this, he used that code, (it's  a simple 2 line tags), u just need to put that into <body></body> tags, and u r all done, bt as a flex, i m nt getting wht to do? coz the rady made code, they provide is some anchor tags of html, so how do i put that in ma mxml, i m confused in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should start with the API Documentation page for the site:
http://www.addthis.com/help/api-overview

I am not at all familiar with the service, but from the docs, it seems that there is a jQuery API and a REST-like interface that the jQuery lib uses.

It seems like you have two options:

1. If you are hosting your flex app in the browser, you might see if you can access the jQuery library to get at the service via the browser.
2. Consider using the REST-like api that they have exported directly in Flex.  You would use the HTTPService to access the API:
   http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html

Good luck!

Comment: Hey Brian,Thanx for the support, yup i need to go through the api, good luck 2 u 2

Comment: @Ankur: If you like my answer, you should at least vote it up... if not mark it as the correct answer, if you feel like it is.

Comment: yaa bro, i'm sry, i shd have done that, well i m waiting for more replies and don't worry when i was replying u, it was running in ma mind, that atleast u answered, so i shd have given u the best answer , bt n e ways, hav this vote up, hav a gr8-2 time